# Creating blob properties with Entity Framework 4?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, flowdocument

I am creating an EF4 model-first application with a WPF UI. One of the controls on my UI is a RichTextDocument, which outputs a WPF FlowDocument. I can either serialize the FlowDocument to a byte array, or extract its XAML markup as a string. I would prefer to use binary serialization, if I can. Here are my questions:

- If I serialize to a byte array, how do I specify an entity property as a byte array in the EDM Designer?
- If I extract a XAML markup string, can I specify that the EDM Designer create the corresponding database column as a `nvarchar(max)` column?

As to the second question, I assume I could always manually edit the *MyModel.edmx.sql* file to change the data type from `nvarchar(4000)` to `nvarchar(max)` before executing it, but I would like to know if it can be done in the Designer.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally got back to this one. Turns out that if it had been any more obvious, I'd have tripped over it. EDM has a `Binary` type that creates a property of type `byte[]` on an entity class. While the types in the EDM Designer generally match CLR type names, that's not true in all cases, as this issue shows.

Answer (score 0):

For nvarchar(max) specify size |maxlength?| as -1 value. As it was described one of in MSDN articles, -1 size value corresponds to MAX sl size specifier, as i remember...